# Easy optimization problem (checking to see my reasoning) - maximum volume of cylinder

Tags: calculus, optimization

> A cylindrical package to be sent by a postal service can have a maximum combined length and girth (perimeter of a cross section) of 108 inches. Find the dimensions of the package of maximum volume that can be sent. (Assume the cross section is a circumference.)

**My answer:**

$$
\begin{align*}
2\pi \cdot r +h&= 108\\
V(r,h) &= \pi r^2 \cdot h \quad \Rightarrow \quad V(r) = \pi r^2 \cdot (108 - 2 \pi r)\\
\\
V'(r) &= 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad -6\pi r^2+2\pi r \cdot 108 = 0
\end{align*}
$$

since $ r \neq 0 $ we have $r = \dfrac{36}{\pi}$ and $h = 36$.

Is my reasoning ok?

Thank you.

Comment: Does "length and girth" mean the sum of the two?

Comment: Yes you are correct Andreas. I actually considered that on my calculations. Thank you.

Comment: There's another typo (squared $\pi$): it should be $-6\pi^2 r^2+2\pi r \cdot 108 = 0$.  The following result is fine.